# foreach para inserir várias rows

Tags: php, html5, mysqli

Estou a tentar inserir numa tabela de MySQL várias rows com o conteúdo preenchido pelo utilizador num formulario HTML, quando mesmo faz submit.

O que necessito é que quando são selecionados varias opções nas options de um select, sejam criadas várias rows na tabela, com as opções escolhidas, individualmente, sendo que o resto dos campos, mantém-se igual.

Isto é o que estou a utilizar, sendo que apenas está a inserir a ultima opção, numa única row, ao contrario do que pretendo.

```
$event = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['event']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date']);
$local = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['local']);
$disc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['disc']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);

foreach($_POST['username'] as $username){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO events (event, date, local, disc, username) VALUES ('$event','".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date))."', '$local', '$disc', '$username')";
}

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($link);
    header('Location: ../events.php');
    exit;
} else {
   echo "ERRO: Não foi possivel inserir o Evento. $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

O formulário html que está a ser processado, é o seguinte:

```
<form action="insert/insertEvents.php" id="newEvent" method="post">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="user">Utilizador</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="username[]" multiple>
                                            <?php
                                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
                                                { echo ' 

                                                <option>'.$row['username'].'</option>';

                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nameEvent">Evento</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="event" class="form-control" id="event">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="reportDate">Data</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class='input-group' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                                </span>
                                                <input type='text' name="date" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="namefat">Local</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="local" class="form-control" id="local" placeholder="ex: Porto">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="namefat">Descrição</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <textarea rows="12" name="disc" class="form-control" id="disc" form="newEvent"></textarea>
                                        </div>   
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
                                    </form>
```

Alguem consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que no seu `foreach` você está substituindo a variável `$sql` e não está concatenando os valores. Logo, sempre será inserido apenas um registro. Neste caso, apenas o último que o usuário selecionou.

**Minha sugestão:**

Substitua isto:

```
foreach($_POST['username'] as $username){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO events (event, date, local, disc, username) VALUES ('$event','".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date))."', '$local', '$disc', '$username')";
}
```

por isto:

```
// string inicial
$sql = "INSERT INTO events (event, date, local, disc, username) VALUES ";

foreach($_POST['username'] as $username){
    // concatenando os valores
    $sql .= "('$event','".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date))."', '$local', '$disc', '$username'),";
}
// retira a última vírgula
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
```

Comment: Já funciona correctamente. Muito obrigado @AndreiCoelho

Comment: @MiglAraújo fico feliz... Abraço!